# How to install an application on a windows server, available to any user in domain on any computer in domain?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server, roaming-profiles, windows-server-2019

I have 5 workstations joint to a domain. The DC is running a Windows Server 2019 Standard Edition and an Active Directory Domain Controller, and a DNS is configured.

I have 20 different users with different privilege levels. For storage saving, is it possible to install the required application (which is a standard win32 application) on the server in a way that is accessible to all authenticated domain users?

What procedures should I proceed with step-by-step, please?

Comment: Installing a general purpose program on a domain controller is a bad idea.  A poorly written program can cause the DC to become unresponsive and cause major issues on your network.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Multiple user sessions and published apps are all common functions in any business network environment, and there's ample documentation on doing this. So what research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: Thank you very much for all your helps. So far, I've installed the RDS, but the main annoying issue is that I have lost my remote desktop access to the server!

Comment: What really is needed to be mentioned here is that, users following this instruction MUST KEEP IN MIND that they will lose their Remote Desktop Access before they configure their RDS as a RD Gateway! If not, the connection is established, but not will be terminated as a higher control level override your permission to connect via remote desktop.
read here:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take note of the above comment by Keltari about installing software on a DC.
I also recommend installing it on another Windows Server computer.

The mechanism I used in the past was RemoteApp.
You may see a detailed writeup in the article
[Step by Step How to Deploy RemoteApp in Windows Server 2016](https://newhelptech.wordpress.com/2017/07/23/step-by-step-how-to-deploy-remote-desktop-services-in-windows-server-2016/).

I have never used it on Windows Server 2019, so I don't know how well it works.
According to reports
([example](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/b3fz9e/windows_server_2019_remoteapp_issues/)),
it may not work too well on Windows Server 2019 Essentials
(this version has been so reduced as to be not very usable),
the Standard version is recommended.

Comment: I succeed to install and configure it, unless I need licenses for that. Although this solution works, however, this is a different solution of what I have in my mind. like at the age of windows server 2008 and earlier, it was possible to install a MS-Office on a storage on the server, and deploy it in the roaming profile of the domain users. and it was working